# Update component properties externally

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to wrap my head around `React`. My requrment is to have two components, which are both displaying the same JSON data in two different ways. I want to call a `Web API 2` method, which will return a JSON result and then re-render the components as soon as the variable holding the data changes. Since these two components need to reflect the same data, I didn't want to make the `$.ajax` call twice. I did a small test component to simulate a part of this process and I can't figure it out.

I have the following `jsx` code:

```
  var Data = {text: "Some Text..."};

  var TestComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="testComponent">
        Hello, world! I am a TestComponent. {this.props.data.text}
      </div>
    );
  },
  updateData: function() {
    this.setProps({data: Data});
  }
});
React.renderComponent(
  <TestComponent data={Data} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);

setInterval(function() {
                Data = {text: "Some other text..."};

            }, 1000);
```

In the `setInterval` method I have tried using both `TestComponent.setProps({data: Data});` directly and also tried calling `TestComponent.updateData();` with both I get an `undefined` error. I also tried `React.TestComponent.` and this is also `undefined`.

I would think this was a simple use case, but I can't find an example of this anywhere. I see a lot of talk about doing this, but no code samples. Maybe I`m going about this all wrong?

Comment: Your return value in the render function is missing quotes I think?

Comment: @alnafie No, see info about JSX, an extension of JavaScript with embedded tags: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to call methods on the `TestComponent` class; instead you should use the instance returned by `React.renderComponent`. Something like this will work:

```
var component = React.renderComponent(
  <TestComponent data={Data} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);

setInterval(function() {
  Data = {text: "Some other text..."};
  component.setProps({data: Data});
}, 1000);
```

though preferred is the more declarative approach of simply calling renderComponent again on the same node, like so:

```
function renderTest(data) {
  React.renderComponent(
    <TestComponent data={data} />,
    document.getElementById('content')
  );
}

renderTest({text: "Some Text..."});
setInterval(function() {
  renderTest({text: "Some other text..."});
}, 1000);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that maybe I should just call `renderComponent` again, but wasn't sure if this was the preferred procedure. Now I know :)

Comment: @EladLachmi No problem. I just updated the docs to hopefully make this a little clearer: [2f61996](https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/2f61996ec30245182c3b783986c2b3b8f50265a0). Would this note have helped you?

Comment: @Ben Alpert seems to me that querying the DOM every time you update the state is not very efficient. Is the root component accessible somehow so that I can run setState on it directly without querying the DOM?

Comment: @lcharbon The root component is returned from ReactDOM.render but it's not recommended to .setState from outside a component because it breaks encapsulation and makes it harder to refactor components safely in the future.